# Gerando um array adequadamente dentro de um método de classe

Tags: php

Tenho uma classe Produtos.

Dentro dela todos os atributos são `private`.

Dentro dela tenho a função abaixo:

```
  public function getArray($cada) {

       $produto = array(
           'idProduto' => $cada->getIdProduto(),
           'tipo' => $cada->getTipo(),
           'modelo' => $cada->getModelo(),
           'bandejas' => $cada->getBandejas(),
           'peso' => $cada->getPeso(),
           'prensagem' => $cada->getPrensagem(),
           'precoUnitario' => $cada->getPrecoUnitario(),
           'comprimento' => $cada->getComprimento(),
           'largura' => $cada->getLargura(),
           'cabo' => $cada->getCabo(),
           'ligacao' => $cada->getLigacao(),
           'potencia' => $cada->getPotencia(),
           'cosumo' => $cada->getConsumo(),
           'corrente' => $cada->getCorrente(),
           'disjuntor' => $cada->getDisjuntor(),
           'descricao' => $cada->getDescricao(),
           'estoque' => $cada->getEstoque(),
           'freteGratis' => $cada->getFreteGratis(),
           'bloqueado' => $cada->getBloqueado()
           );

       return $produto;

  }
```

Acontece que o

```
return $produto
```

está dando

```
Notice: Undefined variable: produto in D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\hotplateprensas.com.br\_controlls\_models\Produtos.php on line 171
```

Linha 171

```
return $produto;
```

Ele gera esse erro e depois gera o array vazio. 
Experimentei criar um atributo e fazer da forma abaixo>

```
$this->produto = array(
...
);
 return $this->produto;
```

Mas aí gera o array vazio mas o erro some.

O que está errado?

Comment: Aparentemente dentro de um dos métodos você não está instanciando a variável produto, qual a estrutura da classe produto?

Comment: É só uma variável local. Não um atributo.Então a instanciação não é como eu fiz, dentro do método?

Comment: Coloque todo o erro!

Comment: alterei ao final da pergunta para colocar o erro completo